# Are Italian residents exempt from needing a UK direct airside transit visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, datv

I am an Indian national and having a `Permesso di Soggiorno` in Italy. It is issued under `Attesa occupazione` status and expires on 23 March 2015.

My wife and my child (under 10 years) are connected to my Italian permesso di soggiorno and are with me in Milan.

Do I need to apply for Direct Airside Transit Visa for the UK?

Comment: What is your departure and destination country?

Answer (score 2):

If your *permesso di soggiorno* is a residence card in the common EEA format that looks like [this](http://ggnitaly84.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/permesso-copy-001.jpg), then you're exempt from needing a Direct Airside Transit visa for the UK.

(Source: [www.gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/no)).

Your wife and child will probably need to hold residence cards of their own.